# MYSQL DELETE query not affecting rows

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a function I have in my php file

```
function deleteLocation() {
        global $con;

        $val = $_POST['id'];
        $escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$val);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM settings WHERE value = '".$escaped."'";

        if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            die("Query failed:" . mysqli_error($con));
        } else {
            die("DELETE FROM settings WHERE value = '".$escaped."'    /    num rows affected: " . mysqli_affected_rows($con));
        }   
    }
```

Here is the text that is returned on the page

```
DELETE FROM settings WHERE value = 'asdasd ' / num rows affected: 0
```

If I take the first part, and run it on my phpmyadmin page,

```
DELETE FROM settings WHERE value = 'asdasd '
```

it will correctly delete the row, but as you can see from the output, 0 rows are affected when the script is run on the page.

If anyone can help to fix this I will be very grateful.

PS: The connection string and user permissions are indeed set up correctly, because every other function in this file works properly

EDIT: Got it, the space at the end of the string was a newline character that was sent from my javascript.

Comment: It looks like your `$val` contains trailing space.  Try trimming it and give it a try: `$val = trim($_POST['id']);`

Comment: What happens when you do a `SELECT *` query with the same `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Trimming it still leaves the space, but even running the query in phpmyadmin with a space works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a pretty unique situation, so I don't know how much this would help other people but,

I had an array of strings that all had \n at the end, so I had to do

```
str[value] = str[value].trim();
```

foreach value in the array. It turns out that this was not a php problem, but rather js

Answer (score 0):

I tried re-creating your problem on my machine and the only time I get the same message as you is when that item was already deleted from the table (or when it wasn't there in the first place)